How do you save Information/data in Python linked to a account with a .txt file?
I am trying to make a simple project where you can save "money" and spend "money" however I want this data to be stored in a more reliable place then just a normal python variable. I would also like it to be stored preferably in a .txt file with a formatting a bit like:
account1
1000
account2
129

with the number representing the amount of money.
I have tried using json.dumps however I couldn't find a way to get a certain accounts "money" (like fetching the money connected to the account specified).

Show us your code.  Assuming you have a list of dictionaries with the accounts and their funds, this should work fine.

If you have the data inside a dictionary you could simply use this to store it inside a file:
data =  {'key':'value1','key2':'value2'}
file = open('info.txt', 'w')
file.write(str(data))
file.close()

Hope this helps.

Okay I will try this is it possible to get the key and its value (im not super advanced at python)?

the output of the file should be exactly this -> {'key2': 'value2', 'key': 'value1'}
